# Outlook removes line breaks UTF-8 and Plain Text mails, regardless of the configuration

Tags: email, outlook

Outlook 2013 up to the latest Office 365 build seem to remove line breaks in Plain Text mails.

Outlook Options:

- E-mail->"Additional line breaks in plain text messages..." = unchecked
- E-mail->"Reduce the size of the message..." = unchecked
- Advanced->International Options = UTF-8
- Let outlook choose codepage is disabled for testing purposes.

If I open a new E-mail, set it to Plain Text and enter:

```
> Foo
> Bar
> Baz
```

the e-mail will still be formatted to:

```
> Foo > Bar > Baz
```

Chaning the international options to Western European ISO will fix this and send the e-mail as intended. System locale is de_DE.

Is there a way to maintain line breaks + UTF-8? Its realy annoying when answering mails.

Comment: The problem is not Outlook, the problem is the email protocol itself.  For plain text, line breaks are ignored as part of the protocol.  The only way around it is to force the email to not be plain text, which causes it to be encoded as an attachment.

Comment: @MarkRansom, while I believe there are flaws and line break issues in SMTP, from naive POV I can send a plain text mail through telnet without further encoding.

Yet the actual problem here seems to be Outlook, Windows 10 and Exchange Policies applied to the Workstation.
\r\n get removed in the process of sending the mail within Outlook. The "Outgoing" Mail is already broken within Outlook, prior touching another SMTP. The TextArea of the Outlook 365 Client within de_DE Windows 10 fails to internally encode UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, leaving it here:

1. Non-english Windows 10:

- Windows Settings App (New Version)
- Date & Region
- Language
- Administrative Language Options
- Language for Unicode incompatible Apps: Change Regional Scheme Button
- Make sure the Country matches.
- **Disable "Beta: Unicode UTF-8 support for worldwide languages"**
  Thats requirement #1.

Full reboot is now needed and cannot be avoided.

2. Outlook 365:

- File
- Settings
- Advanced
- [x] Automatic encoding for Outgoing e-mails
- **Prefered encoding for Outgoing e-mails: Unicode (UTF-8)**
  Thats requirement #2
- Same for vCards.

It seems plaintext messages in de_DE win-10, de_DE outlook 365 + exchange server only work reliable in this combination.

Otherwise any \r\n is removed by Outlook, regardless of the "Remove unneccessary whitespace" setting.